# Makefile, foreach eval, missing separator in define

Tags: foreach, makefile, eval

after reading through plenty of Q/A here, i cannont identify any missing tabs in my targets.mk leading to this error:

../targets.mk:84: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Here goes a code excerpt:

    `define CORNER_TEMPLATE
    .PHONY : ${1}
    ${1} : ${BASEFILENAME}_${1}.lib
    TARGET_FILES += ${BASEFILENAME}${1}.lib
    ${BASEFILENAME}${1}.lib : override TMPDIR = ${BASEFILENAME}.tmp
    ${BASEFILENAME}_${1}.lib : export LIBERATE_CHAR_CORNER_TXT = ${call LIBERATE_CHAR_CORNER, ${1}, ${CELLNAMES}}
    ${BASEFILENAME}_${1}.lib : export LIBERATE_CHAR_TCL_TXT = ${call LIBERATE_CHAR_TCL, ${TMPDIR}, ${1}}
    ${BASEFILENAME}_${1}.lib : ${addsuffix .spi, ${CELLNAMES}}
            @mkdir -p ${TMPDIR}
            @echo "$${LIBERATE_CHAR_CORNER_TXT}" > ${TMPDIR}/corner.tcl
            @echo "$${LIBERATE_CHAR_TCL_TXT}" > ${TMPDIR}/char.tcl
            @cat ${addsuffix .spi, ${CELLNAMES}} > ${TMPDIR}/liberate.spi
            cd ${TMPDIR} && liberate char.tcl
            @touch $$@ 
    endef`

## Line 84:

```
${foreach CORNER, ${CORNERS}, ${eval ${call CORNER_TEMPLATE,${CORNER}}}}
```

Comment: So which line is 84?

Comment: Do all of those `@`-prefixed lines have leading tabs? Because they need them. They are recipe lines.

Comment: Yes, all @-prefixed lines have leading tabs. No whitespaces.

Comment: I may have found the issue:
All the "calls" and "variables" need $$ or $$$$ in order to function properly within a define-function.